# How to remove This action cannot be completed because the other application is busy message

Tags: activex, visual-foxpro, foxpro, activexobject, ocx

Windows 10 desktop application uses upt.ocx control to perform card payments.

If ocx control is busy (waits for pin entry from external usb pinpad or transfers data) and users switches applications, message

> This action cannot be completed because the other application is busy.
> Choose Switch to, Retry or Cancel to activate the busy program and
> correct the problem

appears.

[image]

If retry is selected ocx returns transaction failure but money is still transferred from bank card.

How to disable this prompt ? Application should not respond if ocx is busy or some other method.

Application is programmed in Microsoft Visual FoxPro 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set application.oleserverbusytimeout = 0 to prevent that.

Check:
https://hackfox.github.io/section4/s4g702.html